# String parameter having name of column of database to actual column value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, asp.net-core

I have a method that sends a string parameter(paramType) having name of column of database. and I want to get the value of the column in my Select statement.

I need to replace paramType with value of that column.

```
var details = DetailsRepository
                        .Find(application => application.Created > compareDate)
                        .Select(m => new {m.ApplicationId, paramType })
                        .Distinct();
```

I just need to replace the paramType with name of the column is Select. Suppose I have paramtype = "Address", I want the second element to be m.Address.

Comment: I just need to replace the paramType with name of the column is Select. Suppose I have paramtype = "Address", I want the second element to be m.Address. Hope this clears my question.

Answer (score 0):

If the value of `paramType` is the *name* of a *member*, then to do this you'll have to build an expression tree at runtime. This is *possible*, but is awkward unless all the columns you'll be selecting will always be of the same type.This is *further complicated* by the fact that you want to select a tuple in the lambda. Frankly, it would be easier to write the SQL dynamically in this case...

---

Edit: you could *try* this, which demonstrates the amount of evil needed here:

```
static Expression<Func<Application, T>> BuildTupleSelector<T>(
    string paramType, Func<T> usedForGenericTypeInference)
{
    var m = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Application), "m");
    var body = Expression.New(typeof(T).GetConstructors().Single(),
        new Expression[] {
            Expression.PropertyOrField(m, nameof(Application.ApplicationId)),
            Expression.PropertyOrField(m, paramType)
        },
        new MemberInfo[]
        {
            typeof(T).GetProperty("ApplicationId").GetGetMethod(),
            typeof(T).GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod()
        });
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Application, T>>(body, m);
}
```

with usage:

```
var details = DetailsRepository
   .Find(application => application.Created > compareDate)
   .Select(BuildTupleSelector(paramType,
       () => new { ApplicationId = 123, Value = "abc" }))
   .Distinct();
```

details should now the the anonymous type with an `int ApplicationId` and `string Value`.

Comment: I just need to replace the paramType with name of the column is Select. Suppose I have paramtype = "Address", I want the second element to be m.Address.

Comment: @PiyushChandra yes, I understand what you want to do. It just isn't that simple. As I say, you *can* do this by building an expression tree at runtime. Now: the columns you are interested in: are they all the same type? you mention `Address` - which is presumably a `string`: are *all* the columns that you're interested in also `string`? if so: we can probably *just about* do it, but it will be horribly ugly involving reflection, expression trees, probably abuse of generics, possibly a custom tree-rewriter, etc; what you are asking for *is not trivial*. Writing this as SQL: *is* trivial.

Comment: Yes.. all the columns are string only.

Comment: @PiyushChandra try the code in the edit - see if that works